# Using ruby-oci8 with AIX successfully (no ORA-12537)

Tags: ruby, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Has anyone successfully used the current (2.1.7) version of `ruby-oci8` against Oracle on AIX?

I can run my ruby-oci8 test script and get it to work against TNS for Linux and TNS for Windows but not AIX.

However, it is not an Oracle Instant Client issue, I can do a command line sqlplus connect from my machine to the Oracle (TNS for AIX) server and it works fine. However when I wrap it in a ruby script (using ruby 1.8.7) it fails with:

```
oci8.c:513:in oci8lib.so: ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed (OCIError)
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.7/lib/oci8/oci8.rb:148:in initialize' from app/controllers/testdb.rb:32:innew'
from app/controllers/testdb.rb:32
```

I am not doing anything clever here, just creating a new connection like this:

```
conn = OCI8.new(username, password)
```

Any information on this would be great, I haven't tried packet sniffing - yet....

-John

Comment: So where is the `ruby-oci8 test script`? Paste here, if you need get helps.

Comment: It is really just a one liner (other than the require statement) that looks like what I wrote above, that is: conn = OCI8.new(username, password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually get this working, the short answer is that I had success using the full connection string, that is:
OCI8.new("user/password@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=host.uab.edu)(port=1521))(connect_data=(sid=somesid)))")

The confusing part is that this format isn't mentioned in the API and that I had to use sid= of service_name=.

The details are here:
https://github.com/kubo/ruby-oci8/issues/66